# Netstat showing open established connection but I can't end the process

Tags: windows, networking, command-line, ipv6, netstat

So I've been curious as to know why I have these open established ipv6 connections. I typed in the command prompt Netstat -ano to get the connections, PID numbers, and port numbers. The connections look like this:
[image: Random Ipv6 connections]
You can see the PID number right after my Ipv6 address that is blotted out, and I can't find that on Tasklist under Admin anywhere. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Looks like a Microsoft update server. Surely there are better ways to stop downloading updates, if indeed that's what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking at the source port number, not the PID number. The PID is at the very end of the line (further to the right than your screenshot ends).

Comment: To add to this, a socket is a address:port combination. In those examples, your machine will use that address and port number when sending packets associated with that socket to the address and port number of the device listed next to it. That is how that host knows how to respond back to your machine. The server port is 80, so this is http traffic, so the PID is probably a browser (but not necessarily one).